# CamanJS in SVG?

Tags: svg, camanjs

I'm looking to do some client-side image manipulation using CamanJS (http://camanjs.com/guides/) or some other tool like it on an image within an `<svg>` element.

Sample code is like this...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="624" height="793" id="svg_3162" style="width: 639px;">
    <desc>Created with Rapha�l</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <rect x="15" y="150" width="24" height="24" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff0000" stroke="none"></rect>
    <rect x="7" y="174" width="24" height="24" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="none"></rect>
    MORE SVG STUFF
    <image x="35" y="0" width="600" height="769" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/image.jpg"></image>
    MORE SVG STUFF
</svg>
```

It's getting to the `<image>` tag in the `<svg>` tag that seems to be the issue.  Does anyone know if CamanJS can work with this?  Or if there's something similar out there that can work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

use foreignObject and set height, width, x, and y positions as well

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="624" height="793" id="svg_3162" style="width: 639px;">
<desc>Created with Rapha�l</desc>
<defs></defs>
<rect x="15" y="150" width="24" height="24" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ff0000" stroke="none"></rect>
<rect x="7" y="174" width="24" height="24" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="none"></rect>
MORE SVG STUFF
```

MORE SVG STUFF

Comment: I think your post got cut off.  I don't see anything with `foreignObject` in your post.

Comment: Yes let me give some time